# In Vermont, what determines which prison does a non-binary person goes to?

Tags: criminal-law, transgender, vermont

The non-binary actor Ezra Miller has been charged with felony burglary in Vermont.

In the event a person who does not identify as male or female is convicted and sent to prison in Vermont, how is it decided which prison they go to (or is there a third prison for non-binary inmates)? Is there a process? It is simply automatic by birth sex? Does it matter if a US state has officially recognized the person as non-binary?

Comment: I wish that any downvoters would leave a comment indicting what they think is wrong with this question. In the absence of a comment, the poster cannot improve the post, others cannot edit it to fix the issue, and readers have no idea why someone objects to the post. Such a downvote seems pointless.

Comment: I rather suspect that the authorities will use either birth sex or current physiological sex, that is the state o the genital organs, but I cannot confirm this.

Comment: I would hope the authorities check which place reduces the risk for the prisoner and for other inmates, then check with the prisoner if they agree, and in case of agreement everything is fine. In case of disagreement, heaven knows. And I can see nothing wrong with the question, which is probably of personal interest to hundreds of people or more.

Comment: Not VT specific but see https://www.prisonpolicy.org/blog/2022/03/31/transgender_incarceration/ and https://www.nbcnews.com/nbc-out/out-news/justice-department-reviewing-policies-transgender-inmates-rcna2067 and https://www.nbcnews.com/nbc-out/out-news/federal-court-orders-first-gender-affirming-surgery-trans-prisoner-rcna25377 and https://www.bop.gov/policy/progstat/5200-08-cn-1.pdf and https://www.npr.org/sections/thetwo-way/2018/05/12/610692321/the-guidelines-for-protection-of-transgender-prisoners-just-got-rewritten

Comment: VT specific links: https://www.sevendaysvt.com/vermont/vermont-has-endangered-transgender-prisoners-change-is-coming-but-is-it-enough/Content?oid=32861667 https://www.wcax.com/2021/04/28/will-change-coming-to-vermont-prisons-help-protect-transgender-prisoners/ https://doc.vermont.gov/sites/correct/files/documents/policy/correctional/432.01-gender-identification-care-and-custody.pdf (official policy) https://vtdigger.org/2019/06/18/judge-weighs-lawsuit-brought-by-trans-inmate-against-corrections-officials/ https://mobile.twitter.com/chedgar31/status/1387443815536070658

Comment: I've provided some general and specific links especially the official policy that someone else could use but don't have time to write a proper answer. There is lots of easy to find with a google search information on point.

Answer (score 5):

[This document](https://doc.vermont.gov/sites/correct/files/documents/policy/correctional/432.01-gender-identification-care-and-custody.pdf) answers the question for Vermont. The question "which prison" is not particularly relevant, what matter is "what policies are followed". The DOC defines a reasonably rich set of distinctions, inmates are given a gender preference form at intake, and they do not treat inmates solely on the basis of their identity. There is segregation housing, and an inmate may be assigned to such housing if the facts warrant – and not solely because of their professed or perceived identify.